# undefined index error on image upload

Tags: php, mysql

i get undefined index error line 14. not sure what im missing here. been looking at this for a while.  any help appreciated. not sure how its not getting the index for ['image]. i have already taken out the code to catch the errors in hope to just get  this part to work.

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
 //   
    $firstname = $conn->real_escape_string(isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '');
    $lastname = $conn->real_escape_string(isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : '');
    $dob = $conn->real_escape_string(isset($_POST['dob']) ? $_POST['dob'] : '');
    $moniker = $conn->real_escape_string(isset($_POST['moniker']) ? $_POST['moniker'] : '');




if (isset($_POST['submitBTN'])) {

    $image = $_FILES['image'];
    $imageName = $image['image']['name'];
    $imageType = $image['image']['type'];
    $imageTempName = $image['image']['tmp_name'];
    $imageError = $image['image']['error'];
    $imageSize = $image['image']['size'];
    //get extention
    $fileExt = explode('.', $imageName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
    $allowed = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "pdf", "gif", "GIF");

          $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
          //Here we define where we want the new file uploaded to
          $fileDestination = 'mugshots/'.$fileNameNew;
          //And finally we upload the file using the following function, to send it from its temporary location to the uploads folder
          move_uploaded_file($imageTempName, $fileDestination);



    $query = "INSERT INTO suspects (firstName,lastName,dob,moniker,picture)VALUES(
                                '$firstname',
                                '$lastname',
                                '$dob',
                                '$moniker',
                                '$fileDestination')";

    if ($conn->query($query) === true)  {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
    $conn->close();
}

if (isset($_POST['searchBTN'])) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM suspects WHERE firstName = '$firstname' OR lastName = '$lastname' OR dob = '$dob' OR tats = '$tattoo' OR moniker = '$moniker' ";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)  {
            echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>AGE</th><th>Tattoo</th><th>Moniker</th></tr>";
            // output data of each row
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
                echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"] . "</td><td>" . $row["firstName"] . " " . $row["lastName"] . "</td><td>" . $row["age"] . "</td><td>" . $row["tats"] . "</td><td>" . $row["moniker"] . "</td></tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
        else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

    }
?>
```

my form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="form-group">
    <form action="subjsearch.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="fn" class="col-md-1 col-form-label">FirstName:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" id="fn" name="firstname">
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="ln" class="col-md-1 col-form-label">LastName:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" id="ln" name ="lastname">
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="bday" class="col-md-1 col-form-label">D.O.B:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" id="bday" name="dob" size = "7">
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="mn" class="col-md-1 col-form-label">Moniker:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" id="mn" name="moniker">
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="img" class="col-md-1 col-form-label">Picture:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="file" id="img" name="image">
        </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submitBTN" value="Submit">
        <input type="submit" name="searchBTN" value="Search">
        <input type="reset" name="resetBTN" value="Reset">
    </form> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your form is missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` which is required for file uploads

Comment: Still receiving the same error for undefined index

Comment: Do you get this error when you add a file to the file input?